I'm confused about my new job because it's not my domain should I quit?
I'm new to the healthcare industry (22). I want to do medical coding and have been preparing for about one month. A few days ago I attended an interview at a private healthcare sector and they offered me a position as an AR analyst which I know nothing about, but still I accepted it, I haven't joined yet but I am deeply regretting it.
I'm thinking about requesting to change my department to medical coding.  Will they accept this? If they don't can I quit?
Or can I continue in this position (I have no idea what an AR analyst does but they accepted me for my communication skills).  I am deeply concerned for not getting a job since I graduated, so if I quit this & can I get my desired job.
I'm confused can someone please offer some advice?

keep the job and keep looking for your desired job. worst they can do is fire you

Based on a quick search, it looks like an AR analyst works in Accounts Receivable and makes sure that the company gets paid.

Based on what EJoshua stated, that looks to be a sensitive job that seems much different from what you claim to be qualified in. I would avoid it if I were you and simply tell the truth. Messing this up might end you up in a bunch of hot water.

What is "AR" in this context?

Edit:
Found a better article. You can read it here

I will jump straight to your concerns.

i haven't joined yet but deeply regretting it. I'm thinking about to
change my department to medical coding will they accept my request

I think it mainly depends on what you want to do. If you can't see yourself working as AR Analyst even for "giving it a shot", then you have nothing to lose. Go ahead and ask them before joining that if they would be willing to consider you for that other position.

if they don't can i quit?

It depends upon what says on the contract and if you accepted the offer verbally or if you signed it? If you only verbally accepted the offer, then yes, you can refuse it. If you signed a contract then you probably are legally bound.

Or can i continue in this position

Again, this depends on what you want. Nobody can answer for you.

(i have no idea what an AR analyst do but they accepted me for my
communication skill)

I just googled it and found this article on AR Analyst. Additionally, you can ask the employer to send you a job description or some expected duties you'd be performing.

i quit this & can i get my desired job

Of course! You just only started your career. Everybody's journey is different. Just never be disappointed with rejections, they're a part of job hunting life. The only thing you can and you should do, is keep on trying.
If I were you, I would join in the company, see if the duties somehow align with what I want to do or probably not so different from what I desired. Probably talk to the employer at some point, about changing the department, all the while I keep on looking for the desired job elsewhere.

That article can't seem to decide if it's about Acconts Receivable or Augmented Reality.

@SimonB I should've read through the entire piece, my bad. It was just based off 5 mins research. I will try to find a better one. The idea was that OP can research online as well and also can try asking the employer directly.

AR in healthcare is billing.
